# LinkedIn share button on webpage

Tags: html, css, icons, linkedin-api, social-media

I have a design below which I am trying to replicate on a webpage:

[image]

Right now I am able to get this in the following code (also in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20z2p24k/show/)):

```
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.awardwinnersonly.com" data-text="Czech out the books, movies, and music that won major awards" data-via="BClayShannon">Tweet</a>
    <script>
        ! function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
    </script>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top" class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.awardwinnersonly.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="segoe ui">
</div>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&layout=button&size=small&mobile_iframe=true&width=59&height=20&appId" width="59" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<g:plus action="share" href="https://www.example.com"></g:plus>
```

but not the LinkedIn button. I tried placing it in directly from the [their code generator](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share) but for some reason it doesn't work.

The code generated is the following:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share"></script>
```

I am wondering, am I using the right code as highlighted above for LinkedId button to show up?

Comment: If you wish to avoid downvotes I really suggest you try to edit your question to specifically and as best as you can explain what is the problem you have. Check the docs for each platform and indicate what exactly is not working for you.

Comment: @Oxfist  I have edited my question. Can you check now ?

Comment: I just added the LinkedIn button snippet in the fiddle and I can see the button. What is exactly not working for you?

Comment: The code you want debugged has to be in the question itself, not just at a third party site. Note that JSFiddle's copyright technically doesn't allow us to  edit that code into your question for you (though there is a pending edit where someone's attempting to do so). You need to add that code to your question.

Comment: @Oxfist  I figured it out. Its working in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20z2p24k/1/show/) now

Comment: @user5447339 I'm glad, now if you want the share count implemented don't edit the question to ask that. First search if it has already been asked, and if not create a new question making sure you add the entire code you're working with and pointing out specifically the problem you're having.

Comment: @Oxfist Sure. Can we increase the size of the icons ? Is it possible ?

Comment: @Oxfist  Also, if I am clicking on linkedin button in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20z2p24k/1/show/) it is not generating anything we can share unlike google plus, facebook and twitter where we can actually share. .

Comment: @Oxfist On clicking of linkedin button, the webpage keeps on processing with no result.

Comment: @user5447339 I couldn't get to work on JSFiddle either so I tried it locally with the exact same code and it worked, so I'm guessing there could be something in JSFiddle blocking the redirection of the popup or something, so I think you can confidently try it on your own website.

Answer (score 3):

To simplify what the actual answer was from the given [fiddle of the user](https://jsfiddle.net/20z2p24k/1/)...

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share"></script>
```

However, all this does is produce a button that links to...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Official Microsoft LinkedIn Sharing Documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**

I find it easier to simply use a `<a href ...>` link to solve this problem with an `<img ...>` tag.  That sounds easier than importing an entire JavaScript library.

Comment: saved me a lot of time, thanks for answering.